# c# dataRow access throw a System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, datatable

Can anybody explain why I got `System.ArgumentException`?
code:

```c#
var dsResult = new SecurityYieldsData();//DataSet
var syData = (SecurityYieldsData)base.PrepareCAData(ctx, swiftMessage, caData);
SecurityYieldOptionsData optionsData = GetCaOption(ctx, syData.SecurityYields[0], message.Body);
syData.Merge(optionsData);
dsResult.Merge(syData);
var temp1 = (SecurityYieldOptionsData.SecurityYieldOptionsDataTable)manager.SecurityYieldOptions().GetTable(dsResult);
var temp2 = (SecurityYieldOptionsData.SecurityYieldOptionsDataTable)manager.SecurityYieldOptions().GetTable(dsResult).Copy();
int t1 = temp1[0].OptionNumber;//'temp1[0].OptionNumber' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
int t1_1 = Convert.ToInt32(temp1[0]["OptionNumber"]);// Ok
int t2 = temp2[0].OptionNumber;// Ok
int t3 = optionsData.SecurityYieldOptions[0].OptionNumber;// Ok
```

In DataSet Visualizer from temp1 and temp2 I can see that data exist, but in case t1 I got exeption, if create a copy of temp1 It works fine(see temp2).

Comment: You sure use `var` a lot. That's bad practice. What data type is `t1`?

Comment: Do you get an exception message?

Comment: tnm: in my case OptionNumber is int

Comment: Tim Schmelter: System.ArgumentException: Column 'OptionNumber' does not belong to table SecurityYieldOptions.

Comment: Okay, so what data type is `temp1`? Again, since you use `var` exclusively, I can't tell what it is.

Comment: tnw:I replace some var to type. temp1 is SecurityYieldOptionsDataTable(that means just DataTable)

Comment: @tnw, temp1 and temp2 are of type SecurityYieldOptionsData.SecurityYieldOptionsDataTable, as can be clearly taken from the code.

Comment: If `temp1` "is just a `DataTable`" then it cannot be accessed how you are doing it above. What are you trying to do when you write `int t1 = temp1[0].OptionNumber`?

Comment: @Killercam , I just want to got value from datatable(temp1) from the column "OptionNumber" in first row. and in case temp2 it works fine. I want to undestand why in case temp1 it does not work.

Comment: temp1 is an object and you are implicitly casting to `int`. This maybe your problem. Instead of assuming the object held is an in, use `TryParse` to get first establish whether the conversion was ok, then set the int value.

Comment: @Killercam, temp1 is typed datatable and construction temp1[0].OptionNumber is ok.
If you look on temp2(it's just a copy of temp1) 
int t2 = temp2[0].OptionNumber;// it works fine t2 contains value from table.
The problem only with temp1 and only with construction temp1[0].OptionNumber
when I try to call this construction I got an exception on this line:  System.ArgumentException: Column 'OptionNumber' does not belong to table SecurityYieldOptions.
But when call temp1[0]["OptionNumber"] work fine and I can got value.
Why temp1[0]["OptionNumber"] - works
temp1[0].OptionNumber - doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer on my question. This happens when you merge typed dataset to another dataset and target dataset does not contais typed table.
for example:

```c#
var sourceDataSet = new SomeTypedDataset();
var strongTypedTable = new SomeTypedDataTable()
sourceDataSet.Tables.Add(strongTypedTable );
var targetDataSet = new SomeTypedDataset();
targetDataSet.Merge(sourceDataSet);// at that step targetDataSet will contains strongTypedTable byt this DataTable is not strong-typed
```

if you need save ability to work with strong-typed datatable in targetDataSet you need add to the targetDataSet empty typed dataTable and after that call merge

```c#
var targetDataSet = new SomeTypedDataset();
targetDataSet.Tables.Add(new SomeTypedDataTable());
targetDataSet.Merge(sourceDataSet);
```